# Jscore in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have to write a function called jscore, which takes two inputs s1 and s2.

jscore( s1, s2 )
It takes two strings, s1 and s2 and it should output the jotto score of s1 compared with s2. This jotto score is the number of characters in s1 that are shared by . Repeated letters are counted multiple times, as long as they appear multiple times in both strings.

```
>>> jscore( 'diner', 'syrup' )  # just the 'r'
1
>>> jscore( 'geese', 'elate' )  # two 'e's are shared
2
```

I already have this code:

```
def jscore(s1,s2):
    if len(s1) == 0 or len(s2) == 0:
        return 0
    ss1 = [0] * 26
    ss2 = [0] * 26
    for x in s1:
        ss1[ord(x)-97] = ss1[ord(x)-97]+ 1
    for z in s2:
        ss2[ord(z)-97] = ss2[ord(z)-97]+ 1
        result = 0
    for i in range(0,27):
        result = result + min(ss1[i], ss2[i])
        return result
```

But it keeps returning one less than the actual jscore. jscore('always', 'bananas') returns 2 when it should return three. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your `return` is in the loop. So your loop only runs once.

Comment: Why should it return 3? There are only 2 'a's in 'always'.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only has two errors that I can see, first the return is indented too far so it prevents the final loop from running, second the final loop runs for one iteration too many. Corrected, it produces the expected output:

```
def jscore(s1,s2):
if len(s1) == 0 or len(s2) == 0:
    return 0
ss1 = [0] * 26
ss2 = [0] * 26
for x in s1:
    ss1[ord(x)-97] = ss1[ord(x)-97]+ 1
for z in s2:
    ss2[ord(z)-97] = ss2[ord(z)-97]+ 1
    result = 0
for i in range(0,26):
    result = result + min(ss1[i], ss2[i])
return result
```

You would probably have caught this yourself if you'd tried a few more test cases as the error meant you were only ever checking the letter 'a'.